# Magic Mouse 2 for Mac

Tags: mac, macos, mouse

Magic Mouse 2 appears as it is connected but it will not scroll; when you click on something it will not put on the screen what you clicked on. I have to triple click on the item to get rid of it on the screen.  I would like to know if there is a problem with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum OS requirement is El Capitan, 10.11

Ref: [Apple KB - Magic Mouse 2 - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP730)

> System Requirements
>
> - Bluetooth-enabled Mac computer with OS X v10.11 or later